# Jestjs tests fail in Gitlab CI

Tags: jestjs, gitlab-ci

I'm trying to run Jest tests in Gitlab CI.
The tests succeed locally but when I run them on Gitlab CI I get the following error:

```
Test suite failed to run
ProcessTerminatedError: cancel after 2 retries!

  at Farm.<anonymous> (node_modules/worker-farm/lib/farm.js:81:25)
  at Array.forEach (native)
  at Farm.<anonymous> (node_modules/worker-farm/lib/farm.js:75:36)
  at ontimeout (timers.js:386:14)
  at tryOnTimeout (timers.js:250:5)
  at Timer.listOnTimeout (timers.js:214:5)

A worker process has quit unexpectedly! Most likely this is an 
initialization error.
error Command failed with exit code 1.
```

I tried to add the --runInBand option but this results in a segmentation fault. And I also tried the --maxWorkers option but this results in the same error. Any ideas how to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolved this issue. The problem in my case was not Jest itself but with canvas-prebuilt I'm still not sure what the problem was but I replaced canvas-prebuilt with the canvas npm package and installed the required packages. Now everything works fine.